# MongoDB, How can I update multiple values with condition

Tags: mongodb, express

I using Express in Mongoose,

Result would be like this,,

Consider initial count is 0

```
var arr = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]     
        {
          _id: '1234'
          inventory: [
             {
                itemIndex: 0,
                count: 3  // increate 3 times, since it included upper array
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 1,
                count: 3 // Increase 3 times this, since it included upper array
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 5,
                count: 1 // Increase 1 , since it included upper array
             },     
             {
                itemIndex: 10,
                count: 0
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 11,
                count: 0
             },
          ]
        }
```

** Result would be

```
enter code here
```

I tried this code, but I don't know what should I do.

```
var filter = { _id: id }
await User.updateOne(filter, {
    $inc: {
        clubInventories: {
        itemIndex: ...... ??
    }
   }
},
```

Should I use updateMany instead of updateOne?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [arrayFitlers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/),

- `elem` is a user defined identifier, you can put condition on array field and use that identifier in update part using `$[<identifier>]` positional operator.

```
var filter = { _id: id };
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
await User.updateOne(filter,
    {
        $inc: { "inventory.$[elem].count": 1 }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "elem.itemIndex": { $in: arr } }
        ]
    }
)
```

---

To update different count value in different index then use,

```
var filter = { _id: id };
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var arr1 = [0];
await User.updateOne(filter,
    {
        $inc: { 
            "inventory.$[elem].count": 1,
            "inventory.$[elem1].count": 5 
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "elem.itemIndex": { $in: arr } },
            { "elem1.itemIndex": { $in: arr1 } }
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. But it doesn't works for duplicated array.
i.e) arr = [0,0,0,0,0,1]. it only increase index 0 to 1, how can I increase 0 to 5 times?

Comment: it would not work, refer the link of arrayFilters in answer, if you want to update 0 to 5 then you have to put other conditions in arrayFilters, updating answer for that

Comment: yes and you can not do dynamically update items using single array, you can do as last example.

Comment: If answer is helpful then refer why and how you can [accept answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Actually,         

var filter = { _id: id };
        await User.updateOne(filter,
            {
                $inc: { "clubInventories.$[elem].amount":  arr.count($elem)}
            },
            {
                arrayFilters: [
                    { "elem.itemIndex": { $in: arr } }
                ]
            }
        )

I want to do like this. but it doesn't works.. any ideas?

Comment: this will not work, the only possible way i already added in answer.